Grafana 8.0 table panel using a templating variable to display or hide a column
I got a Grafana 8.4 table panel. I want a variable to control the show hide of a column.
Say,
when control_var = 0 then, the table should show Col1, Col2, Col3,
when control_var = 1, the table should show Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4.
The data source is PostgreSQL. Is this possible?
Tried:

select using case when. But it will show an empty column Col4. That is not what I want. It must be hidden when control_var = 0.

Do block - but the code block cannot return result data.

maybe there are some other ways to get what I want?



Grafana is very limited here. Only thing that supposed to happen is substitution and all logic to be on the db side. And AFAIK, there is no way to return different number of columns like this.

If you are willing to extend scope, you can either generate another variable, that will have a list of columns to be selected (or list of additional columns if you want). Or you can have a variable with optional --, and execute SQL injection on yourself if you feel particularly frisky today ;-)
